# Determine the components of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, simulation

In the context of a numerical simulation I have normally distributed random variables $A$ and $C$. These variables are based on real data. I know that there is a distribution $B$ where $A + B = C$.

Let $A =  N($$\mu_a$,$\sigma_a$)

Let $C =  N($$\mu_c$,$\sigma_c$)

$\sigma_c > \sigma_a$

If I only know $C$ and $A$, how could I go about calculating $B$ using some numerical method?

Comment: Umm, $B = C - A$.  Or do you mean you want the distribution of $B$?

Comment: Yes, I want the distribution of $B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you know are the distributions of $A$ and $C$, you can't determine the distribution of $B$ without some other assumptions.  For example, if 
$A$ and $B$ are assumed independent, then $B \sim N(\mu_c - \mu_b, \sqrt{\sigma_c^2 - \sigma_a^2})$.  But if $A$ and $C$ are assumed independent, then $B \sim N(\mu_c - \mu_b, \sqrt{\sigma_c^2 + \sigma_a^2})$.  And there are
also examples where $B$ does not have a normal distribution at all (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878694/sum-of-dependent-normal-random-variables)).